# How can I stop currently running docker using bash script?

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have scrapers that uses Scrapy Splash using a docker container. I need to start and stop the container using another bash script.

```
run_docker.sh
```

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "run docker"
sudo docker run -itt -p 8050:8050 --rm scrapinghub/splash
```

Comment: Give your container a `--name` and then just `docker stop <name>`. The `--rm` argument might not be helpful in case you are planning to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Add another bash script that will run the scrapers and stops the docker container.

```
stop_docker_container.py
```

```
#! /bin/bash

cd critic_reviews/critic_reviews/spiders

echo "run merlinin-review..."
scrapy crawl merlinin-review
echo "merlinin, done..."

echo "run purexbox-review..."
scrapy crawl purexbox-review
echo "purexbox, done..."

con_id=$(eval "docker ps -q --filter ancestor=scrapinghub/splash")
docker stop "$con_id"
echo "docker container killed..."
echo "done process!!!"
```

The variable `con_id` will return the currently running docker container_id and will be used to stop it.

```
con_id=$(eval "docker ps -q --filter ancestor=scrapinghub/splash")
docker stop "$con_id"
```

I just recently got it. If any improvement needed, feel free to comment below. Thank you.